# Getting Size of a widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm having a Custom Widget A and Custom Widget B in Row or Column, where B depends upon size of A, I can use Layout Builder or render object after the widget A and try to find its remaining space, but `boxconstraints` sometimes give infinity. So the second solution will be `renderbox` and `globalkey` stuff, which will give the size of A only after the screen is rendered, So B needs to wait for the screen to render and after a second `globalkey.findRenderObject` gives the size of A and then we update state and get the size for B then B gets rendered. But I need to get the size of the A widget and use it in B and the screen need to be rendered only once, as using the size and calling setstate after we get the size of A, user can clearly see something happens after the screen has rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at `IntrinsicHeight`/`IntrinsicWidth` widgets but I have described another solution here using a StreamBuilder :

Initialize your StreamController

`final _controller = StreamController<double>()`

in `initState`:

```
...
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => _controller.sink.add(keyA.currentContext.size.width));
...
```

where `keyA` is the globalKey.

In build()

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              key: keyA,
              height: 100,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            StreamBuilder<double>(
                stream: _controller.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData)
                    return Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: snapshot.data,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    );
                  else
                    return Container();
                }),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks, But WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(), means, It is calculated after the initial screen rendering is done, where a user can see Empty Space 1st and some milli second later we can see the new widget B built based on some A widget. Is there any other way? Kindly correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You could also add to the stream before the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` so that it would have some value.  Did you try wrapping your column/row with Intrinsic width/height widgets as an alternate solution?

Comment: We can wrap it with intrinsic height, but my case is like, I'm having A and B widgets with few more widgets in Row/Column and to get Remaining width/height(excluding A and B) and calculate size occupied by A and use it in B to size it or sometimes I make someother calculation in custom painter where B has custom painter. This is a rare case I face.